# What hashing algorithm does RSA use?

Tags: rsa, signature

What hashing algorithm does RSA use ?

Comment: What research have you done, if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question as stated makes no sense. If you have read any details about RSA, this would be obvious, because there is simply no hash function included.

---

Having a guess what you actually meant, this would be RSA with a matching padding scheme, RSA-OAEP in the case of RSA encryption and RSA-PSS if you meant the RSA signature scheme. And then the answer is:

Whatever hash function you choose. Or what the server tells you he accepts, when you are doing a TLS handshake and exchange information about the accepted cipher speccs.